# Видео кодек для файла wmv

Tags: кодек, видео

Windows 7.Пытаюсь запустить файл wmv, идет только звук и выдает сообщение:

> Windows Media Player cannot play thefile because the required video codecis not installed on your computer.

Ставил и видео кодеки для семерки и через другие проигрыватели открывал, та же проблема. Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос. Нужен был кодек: g2m3.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, проигрываемый файл действительно требует кодека, которого нет в системе. Рекомендую попробовать установить [CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/): там практически все, что обычно требуется.

Comment: устанавливал, не помогло

Comment: Тогда попробуйте во время воспроизведения файла щелкнуть его в библиотеке правой кнопкой мыши, затем щелкнуть Свойства. На вкладке Файл просмотреть разделы Аудиокодек и Видеокодек и найти нужный кодек в сети.

Comment: смотрел, стоит video codec - (пусто)

Comment: File: 'E:\2011-04-18 10.10 M10267  RAD u_d.wmv'Possible formats: - .WMV : Windows Media Video (100%) - .WMV : File extensionDetailed analysis: Codecs= TagLib.Riff.WaveFormatEx Codecs= TagLib.Riff.BitmapInfoHeader Duration= 04:26:45.0117000 MediaTypes= Audio, Video Description= Microsoft WMA2 Audio; Unknown Image (G2M3) AudioBitrate= 48 AudioSampleRate= 44100 AudioChannels= 1 VideoWidth= 1024 VideoHeight= 1024 Guid= 75b22633-668e-11cf-a6d9-00aa0062ce6c Guid= d2d0a440-e307-11d2-97f0-00a0c95ea850 OriginalSize= 328 Guid= 44231c94-9498-49d1-a141-1d134e457054 TagTypes= Asf